# compute averages using indices from list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a Python list of lists (both arbitrary size), and a list of float values (also of arbitrary size)

```
a = [[1, 43, 73], [5, 52, 0, 2, 415], [7, 0, 1], ...]
value_list = [4.24, 141.141, 2456.24, ....]
```

What I want to do is:

- for each list in `a`
- get the values from value_list using indices stored in that list in `a`
  (`e.g. for the first list it would be [value_list[1], value_list[43], value_list[73]]`)
- compute the average of these values

such that I will get a list of average values with same size as `len(a)`

I can do that using nested for loop. I am wondering if there are more efficient way to do that since my dataset is quite large.

I have looked into [`numpy.choose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html), but it doesn't work with the 32 choice limitation.

Comment: You said that they are arbitrary in size, but in the example, you show `a` is a list of length 3 lists. Is that always the case?

Comment: Without any bounds on "arbitary size" you already have the best solution. We can define `n` to be the length of a flattened `a`, and then we would do `O(n)` operations: For every element we have a `O(1)` access, followed by a single operation (either a sum or a division). 

You should write the obvious, fool-proof algorithm and do some profiling to see if optimizing it is worth it.

Comment: @jared no it's not always the case. I should have picked a better example. let me modify it

Comment: Simple with numpy.  `value_list[a[0]]` will return those three elements.  You will need at least one loop, because numpy can't handle rows of differing lengths, so you can't convert `a` to an `np.array`.

Comment: What is the *32 choice limitation* you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tim Roberts, we need atleast one loop:

```
>>> value_list = np.random.rand(9)
>>> value_list
array([0.25851398, 0.34346435, 0.64074795, 0.18226188, 0.72841166,
       0.53344045, 0.20196746, 0.23100136, 0.70068062])
>>> a = [[1,3,2], [3,7,1,5], [2]]
>>> for i in a:
...     result.append(np.average(v[i]))
... 
>>> result
[0.3888247262075734, 0.3225420115799865, 0.6407479451568199]
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can tick mark it 